# Detecting Camera in Use on Windows 10

Tags: .net, camera, windows-10

Is it possible, in .NET on Windows 10, to determine whether an attached camera is in use? What I would like to do is each time my camera turns on (e.g. I'm starting a video call), I'd like to capture an event so I can perform some tasks. Once the camera is off, I'd like to capture that event to perform some tasks.

I don't need access to the camera feed - just looking for an event that tells me when the camera state changes.

I've looked at the [AppBroadcastState.CameraCaptureStateChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.capture.appbroadcaststate.cameracapturestatechanged) Event but it doesn't appear to be usable by custom apps (unless I'm missing something basic).

Is this possible?

Comment: Your doc is for UWP. You can't use it for .NET core or .NET framework apps. Usually, you can use WndProc to monitor system events. But it can't monitor the camera status. So, a straightforward way is to set a timer to check the camera status until it is available.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to check the camera status? I am not seeing anything obvious in the Windows messages that WndProc returns. Thanks!

Comment: You can use DirectShow.NET API to detect the camera status. Check my [code snippet](https://github.com/yushulx/dotnet-webcam-barcode-reader/blob/master/BarcodeReaderDemo/DSManager.cs). If your camera is not avaiable, it will throw an exception.

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: I never did find a good solution. An idea that I got from the Microsoft PowerToys project is the notion of using a virtual camera driver that sits in between my application and the camera. I've never written a driver before so I have no idea as to how complex it would be to create but I suspect it wouldn't be trivial. I'm still keeping an eye out for a solution but not actively searching for one at the moment.